# Mask outgoing links

Tags: php, .htaccess, download

On a php web page, i'm displaying an html5 player which plays an mp3 track, and there's a download button next to that. I want to mask the download link only, so visitors will not be able to see the directory tree of my server (www.example.com/content/plugins/audio/downloads/test.mp3). I want to change the link to something more simple and smaller like (www.example.com/download/test.mp3) without changing the folders structure of my server.

I'm not sure if it is an .htaccess or PHP thing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `.htaccess` you would need the following rewrite rule:

```
$ pwd
/var/www
$ cat .htaccess
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/download/(.*\.mp3) /content/plugins/audio/downloads/$1 [NC]
```

It will match all `http://yourdomain.com/download/….mp3` requests and redirect to `http://yourdomain.com/content/plugins/audio/downloads/….mp3`

If you want your .htaccess to work from inside a subdirectory, use `RewriteBase`:

```
$ cat subdirectory/.htaccess
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /subdirectory
RewriteRule ^download/(.*\.mp3) content/plugins/audio/downloads/$1 [NC]
```

i.e. `http://yourdomain.com/subdirectory/download/….mp3` to `http://yourdomain.com/subdirectory/content/plugins/audio/downloads/….mp3`

Comment: So if i put a link on my website like (www.example.com/download/test.mp3) it will redirect to (www.example.com/content/plugins/audio/downloads/test.mp3) ?

Comment: @Manolis: apache will rewrite the original url and return the `content/plugins/…` file instead.

Comment: The download link looks like this: `<a href="<?php echo htmlentities($audio, ENT_QUOTES); ?>" class="jp-download" title="Download"></a>` 

So the mp3 filepath is $audio. Is there a quicker way to change the way it appears? I'm not sure if you understand what i mean, maybe another way instead of htaccess? Thanks.

Comment: @Manolis: I'm not sure I understand. You said you wanted to provide a simple link like `download/audiofile.mp3` which, when clicked will retrieve another file (`content/plugins/…/…/…/audiofile.mp3`). .htaccess will do exactly that; rewrite requests.

Comment: A link like: `http://localhost/site/download/test_audio.mp3` doesn't redirect to `http://localhost/HHVIP/content/plugins/audio/downloads/test_audio.mp3`. 

Is the above code right?

Comment: Why would it? `^site/download` is different from `^download`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7128/discussion-between-manolis-and-knittl)